# How to customize Magento webservices to return proper json data for parsing in android application?

Tags: android, json, web-services, magento, android-ksoap2

I am new in magento. I want to customize json result of magento webservices.
I am using KSOAP 2 to call magento webservice.
Following is the result from api,
current result format is:

```
catalogCategoryTree{category_id=1; parent_id=0; name=Root Catalog; position=0; level=0; children=ArrayOfCatalogCategoryEntities{item=catalogCategoryEntity{category_id=2; parent_id=1; name=Apparels and Accessories; is_active=1; position=1; level=1; children=ArrayOfCatalogCategoryEntities{item=catalogCategoryEntity{category_id=4; parent_id=2; name=Men's; is_active=1; position=1; level=2; };};};};
```

And required json format is

```
{"categoryList":[{"CategoryID":"105","CategoryName":"Men Apparels","SubMenuID":"1","count":"11"}]}
```

Comment: did you get solution to this problem?